# NodeJS/SocketIO Socket will not emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to 'emit' data to the server, but nothing is happening.
The console says that I've connected, but it won't log anything whenever
I try to emit the specific command.

Clientside (JQuery/JS):

```
    var ip = "";
    $.ajax({
        url : "../host",
        success : function(result){
            ip = result;
        }
    });

    var socket = io.connect(ip);
    socket = io('/admin');

    socket.on('add_task', function(name, event, command, args) {
        AddTask(name, event, command, args); //I get this data from the server
    });

    socket.on('remove_task', function(name) {
        DeleteTask(name); //I get this data from the server.
    });

    $("#addTask").click(function() {
        var args = ["add", $("#nameData").val(), $("#eventData").val(), $("#commandData").val(), $("#argData").val()];
        socket.emit("task", args); //This won't emit anything.
        $("#add-modal").modal("hide");
    });
```

Serverside (NodeJS):

```
admin.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log("An admin has connected."); //This logs

task.get().forEach(function(tsk) {
    var tdata = tsk.split(':');
    admin.emit('add_task', tdata[0], tdata[1], tdata[2], tdata[3]); //This sends
});

admin.on('task', function(args) {
    console.log(args); //This doesn't log
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen for the event on the connected socket, like so:

```
admin.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('task', function(args) {
    console.log(args);
  });
});
```

This is because the event comes from the connected socket, otherwise socket.io would have no way of knowing which socket the event came from and the event's associated data would be meaningless.

Comment: I am, I left that out. Editing now

Comment: It still looks like you're referencing `admin` when you should be referencing `socket`.